# Optim() in R gives me different values with Excel Solver plug-in

Tags: r, excel, optimization

I'm working on a very simple optimization(linear) problem which is extremely easy on excel but gives different values when I tried it with R's optim() or optimize(). The function is to get risk aversion coefficient. wc is the answer of respondents though I gave value by myself.

```
p <- 0.3
w1 <- 2.0
w2 <- 0.0
mean <- p*w1+(1-p)*w2
variance <- p*w1^2+(1-p)*w2^2-mean^2
wc <- 0.4

f<- function(x){(abs(mean-wc+0.5*x*variance))}
initial_x <- c(0.1)
x_optimal <- optim(initial_x, f, method="CG")
x_min <- x_optimal$par
x_min
[1] -0.4761905
```

The target function is just linear equation with one variable and all the other variables are settled. 
When I calculated it with Excel solver the optimal value of x is 0.4761905 (yeah, exactly the same number only without the minus sign).

I also tried other method like 'Brent', 'SANN' but they gave me totally different values. 
I heard the optimize() function is for linear optimization, so I tried it too but also gave me wrong value again. Can you tell me the reason?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Next time you post please try to post a [reproducible example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). We do not have any excel code, so I can not tell you why your answer is of a different sign. Your R code returns the correct solution. The reason why the answer is opposite in Excel is probably due to the absolute value. Also, you shouldn't use a general purpose gradient based optimization routine to answer a linear problem. Just `solve(.5*variance, mean-wc)` which returns the value `0.4761905`.

Answer (score 0):

You've not given any details of how your calculations in Excel were performed, but these seem to be wrong, not R. To illustrate:

```
x <- (-1000:1000)/1000
plot(x,f(x))
```

shows the minimum close to -0.5. You can also solve the problem analytically, by setting the derivative of f(x)^2 equal to zero to give a solution of `(wc-mean)/(0.5*variance)`.

Note that the differences between the optimisers are minimal, and can almost certainly be reduced by reducing tolerances or increasing number of iterations.

```
optim(initial_x, f, method="CG")$par
#[1] -0.4761905
optim(initial_x, f, method="Brent",lower=-10, upper=10)$par
#[1] -0.4761905
optim(initial_x, f, method="SANN")$par
#[1] -0.475279
optimize(f,c(-10,10))$minimum
#[1] -0.4761772
```